# Attempted to load class "IntlTimeZone" from the global namespace

Tags: internationalization, timezone, php-7, php-extension

When I installed first time symfony application it loudly failed with the error:

```
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Attempted to load class "IntlTimeZone" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Can be fix by installing, php module which is missing.
In my case ubuntu 16 with php 7.2 on it:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl
```

Comment: Remember restart apache... If yo're using symfony server:run restart it.

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-intl

Answer (score 0):

If using window and composer you can try

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

this work for me.